# Number::toString() abstract operation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, type-conversion

I'm trying to understand how the [Number::toString(x)](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-numeric-types-number-tostring) abstract operation works.

From what I can make out, the gist of it seems to be that very large (n > 21) and very small (n < 6) numbers are represented in scientific notation (step 10):

`String(1.5e22) // => "1.5+22"`

...everything else is represented in decimal notation (steps 6-9)

`String(1.5e1) // => "15"`

This is the fifth step:

> 5. Otherwise, let `n`, `k`, and `s` be integers such that `k ≥ 1, 10k - 1 ≤ s < 10k`, the Number value for `ℝ(s) × 10ℝℝ(n) - ℝ(k)` is `x`, and `k` is as small as possible. Note that `k` is the number of digits in the decimal representation of `s`, that `s` is not divisible by `10ℝ`, and that the least significant digit of `s` is not necessarily uniquely determined by these criteria.

1. Why are the constraints in step 5 required?

   Namely, that **`k` is as small as possible**, **`10k - 1 ≤ s < 10k`** and **`s` is not divisible by `10ℝ`**.
2. How are the values of `n` and `k` found?

   For the number 1.5e1, the smallest `k` for **`10k - 1 ≤ s < 10k`** and `k ≥ 1` to both be true is 2, which would mean n = 2. But this doesn't seem to be correct, since it takes me to step 6 (as `k ≤ n ≤ 21`), which doesn't produce the string "15".
3. What use case does step 6 correspond to?

> 6. If `k` ≤ `n` ≤ 21, return the string-concatenation of:
>
>    - the code units of the `k` digits of the decimal representation of `s` (in order, with no leading zeroes)
>    - `n` - `k` occurrences of the code unit 0x0030 (DIGIT ZERO)

Comment: As a side note: I occasionally check against ES1 which sometimes helps clarify newer specs. [Here is the spec for ES1 (PDF)](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_1st_edition_june_1997.pdf). The `toString` algorithm is on page 43 of the PDF (number on the page is 31) - it's section 9.8.1. In this case, it seems like exactly the same algorithm. The notes after the steps are very similar, too.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and for making the edits @VLAZ. Yes, the wording seems to be identical in this case. Hopefully, someone will be able to shed some light.

Comment: Yep, in this case doesn't help. I gave that for future reference. The ES1 spec is drastically smaller, which can help in some cases. The newer specs are *huge* and further tend to divide an algorithm in several different places (because different parts are used in different places). Which is where the older spec is sometimes handy in having things in the same place. Sometimes there are also additions in later specs but the core would be the same.