# Number.prototype.toString (for floats) implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently found out that you can call `toString()` on floating point numbers in JS with a radix, but I'm confused on its implementation.  For example, `3.1459.toString(16)` in JS, returns `3.2559b3d07c84c`.  From my testing it seems that the numeric part is a straightforward conversion to the equivalent radix, but this doesn't hold true for the fractional part?  How exactly are the characters determined?

I've found what I believe is the [source](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/numbers/conversions.cc#L1269) for that in V8.  It is similar to what was posted in the comments about converting the fraction to hexadecimal, but there is additional rounding and precision differences.

Comment: Is this question about JavaScript or C#? If the question is about the implementation of `toString` for `Number` values, we don't really care that you are trying to port to C#, unless you only want answers in terms of C# code.

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity, I don't mind code for either but I removed the C# tag since it's more geared torwards JS itself.

Comment: There isn't anything on MDN that goes into details for how fractional numbers are converted. Looking at [the spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number.prototype.tostring) it says "*The precise algorithm is implementation-defined, however the algorithm should be a generalization of that specified in 6.1.6.1.20.*" and links to [this section](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-tostring) but I go cross-eyed trying to read and understand it.

Comment: Somewhat related - there was a recent question about that part of the spec: [Number::toString() abstract operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66758381). However, there are no answers so far.

Comment: Another related question, language agnostic question: [How to convert decimal fractions to hexadecimal fractions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20650954/215552)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for converting a decimal fraction to a different radix system, you could multiply the fractional part with the radix, get the integer value in the radix like notation and perform the same until you get zero or get a limit of digits.

```js
let frac10 = 0.1459,
    frac16 = '',
    limit = 15;

while (frac10 && --limit) {
    const integer = Math.floor(frac10 *= 16);
    frac16 += integer.toString(16);
    frac10 -= integer;
}

console.log(frac16);
```

Comment: This is a clean and simple solution, but this doesn't handle edge cases that you get when have carry-overs from multiplying.  https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/numbers/conversions.cc#L1309-L1330